# Flash crashing in firefox

Tags: firefox, flash, crash, youtube

When watching youtube videos flash will occasionally crash, this almost always happen when i change the system volume or hit mute. I've tried removing flash and reinstalling with apt install flashplugin-installer, but I'm still experiencing this problem.

Comment: Can you open FireFox in terminal (type `firefox` and hit Enter).  This should output any error and debugging messages FireFox produces, in terminal.  Then copy the details into a comment, or an edit of your question.

Comment: Why don't you use the HTML5 YouTube player?

Answer (score 0):

Now I do feel a bit like a cock, it turned out I had an add-on which blocked the html5 player, so I got it working now!

Comment: Which addin? Maybe I have same:)